# Rails: Call a method from a model in Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

Trying to call a method from `scenario.rb` which contains a method called complete_scenario? which returns a boolean inside the migration file but an error states that `complete_scenario?` is an undefined_method.

```
class AddCompleteFlagToScenarios < ActiveRecord::Migration

def up
change_table :scenarios do |s|
  s.boolean :complete, s.complete_scenario? :default => false, :null =>false
end

end

def down
  remove_column :scenarios, :complete
end

end
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or forgetting to include? Ultimately, I want to add a new column to Scenario called complete that takes the boolean from Scenario and puts it into the updated table. 
Thanks.

```
class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name,
presence: true,
uniqueness: { :case_sensitive => false },
length: { in: 4..60 }

has_many :nodes
has_many :showings, -> { visible }
has_many :courses, :through => :showings

attr_accessor :warnings

amoeba do
enable
include_association [:nodes]
end

...

def complete_scenario?
   (self.unlabeled_choices.empty?) && (self.no_goal_nodes?) && (self.regular_leaf_nodes.empty?) && (self.unconnected_nodes.empty?)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 'up', so it looks like below:

```
def up
 change_table :scenarios do |s|
  #here s is not ActiveRecord object, rather refers to table, s.complete_scenario? is invalid here, so instead do below
  s.boolean :complete, :default => false, :null =>false
 end
 #here you set the complete field for all rows in the table
 Scenario.find_each do |s| 
   s.complete = s.complete_scenario?
   s.save!
 end
end
```

**OR**

A better approach is to populate/seed the new column in db/seed.rb,

Change your 'up' in the migration file to below:

```
def up
 change_table :scenarios do |s|
  s.boolean :complete, :default => false, :null =>false
 end
end
```

In db/seed.rb add this line (or you can use a separate rake task for below):

[RailsCasts explanation here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)

```
 Scenario.find_each do |s| 
   s.complete = s.complete_scenario?
   s.save!
 end
```

Comment: Referencing model names in migrations is not recommended because models are susceptible to change and retirement, whereas migrations are expected to remain static, and, when they do change, can have ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing model names in migrations is not recommended because models are susceptible to change and retirement, whereas migrations are expected to remain static, and, when they do change, can have ramifications.

So, in general, `ActiveRecord::Migration` should not concern itself with the `ActiveRecord::Base`.

I do not know what `unlabeled_choices`, `no_goal_nodes?`, `regular_leaf_nodes` or `unconnected_nodes` do internally, but, if possible, you should use the appropriate (series of) database join(s) to populate the `:complete` attribute with.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I solved it by doing this:

```
def up

  add_column :scenarios, :complete, :boolean

  Scenario.find_each do |s|
    s.complete = s.complete_scenario?
    s.save!
  end

end

def down
   remove_column :scenarios, :complete
end
```

Comment: The approach of directly referencing an `ActiveRecord::Base` model in a migration is highly recommended against.

Please review this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835321/rails-call-a-method-from-a-model-in-rails-migration#answer-44840153